# Should I replace an old SSD that was used for an average of six hours per day over the last four years?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssd

**Context:** I wanted to install another OS and I was thinking, depending on the use I had of my actual SSD which already been used for more than **8464 hours**.

---

Do you think I should Upgrade to another one or I can keep this one longer?

*In order to provide you more details: I use it since 4 years almost daily for my studies.*
So the choice is important because I can not afford it to be out of order in the 2 years that are coming

[image]

Comment: If you have used it for 4 years and feel it’s time to replace it, then replace it. But honestly, it might be fine as well. Your choice and comfort level.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably continue to use the SSD, though I'd make sure that the data stored on it is backed up regularly.

- This SSD is an OEM model manufactured by Kingston Technology (see [this Tom's Hardware forum thread](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/references-of-kingston-rbu-sc100s37128gd.2038814/) for details). From what I can find, it used planar MLC NAND. You have 8.5 TBW of host writes on the drive, with 12.4 TBW of raw NAND writes (for a [write amplification factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification) of 1.46x). I have little reason to believe that the NAND is failing any time soon; you should be able to put 100+ TBW on the drive before there's any real chance of trouble.
- The number of hours on the drive is equivalent to one year of continuous operation, or six hours per day over the last four years. This is not much more from the eight hours per day, five days per week that most consumer SSDs are designed to handle, so your usage profile isn't unusually heavy.
- The firmware version (starting with S8FM) indicates that the drive is powered by a **Phison PS3108-S8** controller. Despite its age, the Phison S8 has a very good reliability track record; however, there is a somewhat higher risk of controller failure than with a new drive. I wouldn't worry about it too much at this point, and would just make sure the drive is backed up.

SSDs are generally more reliable than hard drives, but they often provide little warning that they're about to fail, unlike hard drives where imminent failure can often be predicted using SMART information. I'd continue to monitor the SMART status and back up data regularly to protect against data loss in the event it does fail. In CrystalDiskInfo, you can use the **Startup** and **Resident** options under the **Function** menu to have it automatically launch when you log in to Windows and stay running in the background so it can continuously monitor drives and warn you if the drive's SMART information indicates a problem with the drive.

Answer (score 1):

The SMART data look fine (no reallocated sectors yet...), so no hurry.

However, I also take advantage of a reinstall to replace/upgrade disks. I keep backups so a disk failure is not a life-threatening experience, but when it happens I have to make an emergency purchase and I can't spend time to find the best deals. Also in your specific case, the price of SSDs has dropped somewhat in the last 4 years and a 128GB SSD starts to look small.